# Sorting database values using usort and Sortby(collection method)

Tags: php, database, laravel, controller, usort

I am trying to use usort and sortby to basically after the code below is
1. sort $featureLists by 'feature_sort_order'
2. loop over each $featureList and reset sort order to integer a contiguous value

my Petitions table has feature_sort_order column having values 1 to 6 
 i used this part of code in controller :

```
$featureList = Petition::getFeaturedPetitions();
$Petition->featured_sort_order = Input::get('dropdown_menu_list');
foreach($featureList as  $featureLists)
{
    if($featureLists->feature_sort_order >= $Petition->featured_sort_order && $featureLists->id != $Petition->id)
    {
        $featureLists->feature_sort_order += 1;
    }
}
```

Here what i trying to do is select a value from dropdown menu and to change current item position before selected item.

i have tried few things like this but doesn't work out :

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

function sortBy(&$items, $key) {
    if (is_array($items)) {
        return usort($items, function($a, $b) use ($key) {
            return cmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
        });
    }
    return false;
}

sortBy($featureList, 'featured_sort_order');

// foreach($featureLists->feature_sort_order as featureOrder)
 // {


// }
```

Comment: What is the result of your if statement? Where is the problem? What is the error? If no error, what is occurring that doesn't seem to be functioning as intended?

Comment: Why not sort in your database query?

Comment: it's like suppose i have selected item 2 from dropdown menu so i want to my put current item (4) before that.  And arrange everything in 1 to 6 order after that by renumbering them.